# Building error after updating Xcode from 5.0 to 5.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I am developing an iOS App.

I updated Xcode version from 5.0 to 5.1.
While on version 5.0, no problems happened in building. However after updating to 5.1, the following error happens:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: re-run `pod install` in the directory containing your Podfile.

Comment: Nice! I added my comment as an answer. Please accept/upvote it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuild the Pods' xcodeproj by running

```
pod install
```

in the directory containing your Podfile.